# LINQ to Entity query optimization

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I currently have the following logic that builds a list of 4 integers, where each integer represents a sum of all votes for a certain item ID (1, 2, 3 or 4):

```
List<int> totals = new List<int>();

using (RepositoryEntities entityContext = new RepositoryEntities())
{
    totals.Add(entityContext.ItemVotes.Count(v => v.Vote == 1));
    totals.Add(entityContext.ItemVotes.Count(v => v.Vote == 2));
    totals.Add(entityContext.ItemVotes.Count(v => v.Vote == 3));
    totals.Add(entityContext.ItemVotes.Count(v => v.Vote == 4));
}
```

This works very well, but I'm questioning the efficiency of such querying, because this seems to actually generate and execute 4 separate queries.  Ideally I'd want to have a single, efficient query that returns me the 4 sums.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: might want to look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336747#countGrouped

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your logic into one query

```
totals.AddRange(entityContext.ItemVotes
    .Where(iv => iv.Vote >= 1 && iv.Vote <= 4)
    .GroupBy(iv => iv.Vote)
    .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
    .Select(grp => grp.Count());
```

(This code is untested and could be way off base but just throwing out an idea)

Comment: Looks promising, but kvp.Values does not exist.

Comment: Getting close.  But if any of the votes have a count of zero, they are not in the list.  For example, my original query returns a list:  0, 1, 3, 0.  But your list returned is just:  1, 3.  Took out Where clause and no change.

Comment: Well, this doesn't yield the exact result I was looking for, but it's close enough to get someone on the right path.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

in LINQ the .Count() method forces execution of a query. If you need 4 different totals there is no other way to produce that in one statement.